# Neovim Go to Definition not work as expected in Windows WSL

Tags: neovim

I was trying to setup neovim on my Windows 11 PC using WSL. Everything seems fine but the 'go to definition' is not working properly. For example when I try to go to definition it only goes to the import statement.

My config are currently working in my mac and the 'gd' works fine in the mac.

There is no error or error log. Windows developer mode is also turned on.

Following is my lsp config

```
local lsp_zero = require('lsp-zero')

lsp_zero.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
  local opts = {buffer = bufnr, remap = false}

  vim.keymap.set("n", "gd", function() vim.lsp.buf.definition() end, opts)
  // some other keymaps
end)

require('mason').setup({})
require('mason-lspconfig').setup({
  ensure_installed = {'tsserver', 'rust_analyzer'},
  handlers = {
    lsp_zero.default_setup,
    lua_ls = function()
      local lua_opts = lsp_zero.nvim_lua_ls()
      require('lspconfig').lua_ls.setup(lua_opts)
    end,
  }
})

local cmp = require('cmp')
local cmp_select = {behavior = cmp.SelectBehavior.Select}

cmp.setup({
  sources = {
    {name = 'path'},
    {name = 'nvim_lsp'},
    {name = 'nvim_lua'},
  },
  formatting = lsp_zero.cmp_format(),
  mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
    // mappings
  }),
})
```

I work with typescript and rust. 'gd' does not work in both type of projects and it only go to the import statement only. However the same config in mac works fine.

```
// Packer config
  use {
      'VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim',
      branch = 'v3.x',
      requires = {
          -- LSP Support
          {'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'},
          {'williamboman/mason.nvim'},
          {'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim'},

          -- Autocompletion
          {'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'},
          {'hrsh7th/cmp-buffer'},
          {'hrsh7th/cmp-path'},
          {'saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip'},
          {'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp'},
          {'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lua'},

          -- Snippets
          {'L3MON4D3/LuaSnip'},
          {'rafamadriz/friendly-snippets'},}
      }
```

What am I missing here ? I tried to use neovim on native windows as well. I was able to setup it through Scoop. However it didn't worked out as neovim fails to open files are freeze with no error. So that's why I tried with WSL.

LSP log - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-8Tk1c6Pue1Z1p7yXmDVNXt8vaC8WQuD/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what fixed the problem, but I removed everything, uninstalled neovim and the configs by running

```
rm -rf ~/.config/nvim
rm -rf ~/.local/share/nvim
```

Then I installed just the `treesitter` and the `lsp` with the same lsp config in the question.

```
use('nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter', {run = ':TSUpdate'})
use {
  'VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim',
  branch = 'v3.x',
  requires = {
    --- Uncomment these if you want to manage LSP servers from neovim
    {'williamboman/mason.nvim'},
    {'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim'},

    -- LSP Support
    {'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'},
    -- Autocompletion
    {'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'},
    {'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp'},
    {'L3MON4D3/LuaSnip'},
  }
}
```

Also there was `coc` installation that I did long time ago that didn't deleted completely. I removed that too,

```
cd ~/.config && rm -rf coc
```

For some reason this fixed the issue. Later I added all other plugins and everything seems working fine.